# Why are my functions executing in the wrong order?

Tags: javascript

I want to know why my program outputs `I4 output` then `I3 output`？

```js
var a = 4;
var i = 0;
var i3 = function() {
  console.log("I3 output")
  return i = i + 3
}
var i4 = function() {
  console.log("I4 output")
  return i = 4
}

(a > 3) && i3() || (a < 5) && i4();
console.log(i)
```

I want `I3 output` then `I4 output`. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: `(a > 3) && i3()` the first part, `a > 3` is false, so the second one isn't evaluated

Comment: @Cid but `a===4` so `a > 3` though

Comment: @JeremyThille someone (me!) shouldn't do code **before** coffee

Comment: There are many related questions like [TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function](/q/31013221/4642212) or [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](/q/2846283/4642212).

Answer (score 9):

It's because you are missing a semicolon.

This :

```
var i4 = function() {
  console.log("I4 output")
  return i = 4
}

(a > 3)
```

is executed like this :

```
var i4 = function() {
  console.log("I4 output")
  return i = 4
}(a > 3) // <--- You are executing i4, passing it "a > 3" as argument
```

Sidenote : Javascript allows you to do this, leading to a bug; but Typescript complains. It says that you are calling a function with 1 argument, when it expects 0. Typescript really is some improvement over JS and taught me a lot about it.

If you add a semicolon, the function is defined, but not executed :

```js
var a = 4;
var i = 0;
var i3 = function() {
  console.log("I3 output")
  return i = i + 3
};

var i4 = function() {
  console.log("I4 output")
  return i = 4
}; // <-- Add semicolon

(a > 3) && i3() || (a < 5) && i4();
console.log(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

First I'd urge you start using semi-colons. ASI (Automatic Semi-colon Insertion) is an [*error correction* process](https://brendaneich.com/2012/04/the-infernal-semicolon/), and you'll find these kinds of errors creeping in if you don't.

Second, further to that, maybe consider function declarations rather than function expressions. Again, you're missing semi-colon at the end of `i4` is the issue causing the problem which can be avoided with a declaration instead which don't need to terminate with them.

Third, if you're looking to call *both* functions you need to call them *separately*. If you use a [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) the second expression won't be evaluated because the first will always evaluate as truthy.

```js
var a = 4;
var i = 0;

function i3() {
  console.log('I3 output');
  return i = i + 3;
}

function i4() {
  console.log('I4 output');
  return i = 4;
}

(a > 3) && i3();
(a < 5) && i4();

console.log(i);
```